# How do you get access to the instance of a downgrade component in the view?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade

I've tried the usual `#instance` on the component without success. I figured that would work since inputs and outputs still work with `[]` and `()`. But `instance` is `undefined`. How do I get a ref to the instance from angularjs? I need to be able to call a function in the downgraded angular component.

EDIT: This question is not related to the question that was marked as duplicate. Please reread and reconsider. This question is asking about how to get an instance of the downgraded component in the angularjs view. That question was asking how to create a downgrade component. I'm obviously already past that point.

Comment: Is your question related to angular or angularjs?

Comment: Both, which is why I tagged it as such.